# Is it possible to detect element creation event in Shadow-dom?

Tags: html, event-handling, contenteditable, shadow-dom

When you activate `contenteditable` in the div and enter text, the shadow dom form looks like the following.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"> 
<div>1번줄</div> 
<div>2번줄</div> 
</div>
```

If you enter text and hit enter, a new div is created and the entered text is placed inside the created div.

Is there any way to detect child element creation event of editor?

And is there a related example where I can create functionality like contenteditable in a way that doesn't use contenteditable ?

I can't quite remember the keywords.

Comment: Remember that the code-snippet you've shown here is simple HTML. And HTML is a markdown language: There is no logic in it (if/else). Therefore, what you've posted can never detect anything. If you want to detect it, then I would suggest looking into adding some JavaScript to your code.

Comment: try a ``mutationObserver`` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver